# Edit inside an HTML tag with ed(1)

Tags: regular-expression, html, ed

Consider my humble *`hello.html`* file, edited with mighty ed:

```
$ ed hello.html 
28
,p
<title>Hello world!</title>
```

What's your general approach to edit inside that *title* HTML tag (bonus if you can edit inside any HTML tag)?

I tried a regular expression that matches inside the tag:

```
s/>.*/>My new title/p
<title>My new title
u
.
<title>Hello world!</title>
```

But, sadly, you can see that I chopped my tag (and it would be way too much work to type out that *`</title>`* bit every time!).

For further education, I browsed through Software Tools in Pascal page to 174—see https://archive.org/details/softwaretoolsinp00kern/page/174/mode/1up?view=theater page—and discovered the *`&`* special character that helpfully reaches the *middle* of the sentence:

```
s/world/& again/p
<title>Hello world again!</title>
```

But, that's not quite right, since I want to substitute the middle, not just reach the middle.

Comment: For a quick change, I would do something like `s/>[^>]*</>My new title</`, but you'd have to provide some representative input and output for us to say what might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[^<]` instead of `.` to match any character other than `<` instead of any character.

```
28
ed> ,n
1       <title>Hello world!</title>
ed> s/>[^<]*/>new title/
ed> ,n
1       <title>new title</title>
```

Another approach could be to insert newlines before and after each `<` or `>` so the thing you want to change is on its own line which you can `c`hange with `c`:

```
28
ed> ,n
1       <title>Hello world!</title>
ed> s/[<>]/\
&\
/g
ed> ,n
1
2       <
3       title
4       >
5       Hello world!
6       <
7       /title
8       >
9
ed> 5c
new title
.
ed> ,n
1
2       <
3       title
4       >
5       new title
6       <
7       /title
8       >
9
ed> 1,9j
ed> ,n
1       <title>new title</title>
```

Comment: Excellent! That `>[^<]*` regex is very creative and straightforward. I also like that you only need to repeat a the front `>` instead of the `>` and `<` like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768628/edit-inside-an-html-tag-with-ed1/768646#comment1467210_768628 comment.

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to use an HTML-aware parser and use that to edit content. My preferred tool is `xmlstarlet` because although it's an XML parser/editor it can also handle HTML:

Create a sample page

```
cat >my.html <<'EOF'
<html>
<title>Hello world!</title>
<body><p>Thank you for reading my page</p></body>
</html>
EOF
```

Replace `Hello world!` with `Hello everyone!`:

```
xmlstarlet format --html my.html 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --update '//title' --value 'Hello everyone!'

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello everyone!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you for reading my page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output is written to *stdout*, and the usual approach here is to write it to a temporary file and then replace the original. This isn't perfect but it's probably acceptable:

```
file=my.html
(
    [ "${file#/}" = "$file" ] && file="./$file"

    xmlstarlet format --html "$file" 2>/dev/null |
        xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --update '//title' --value 'Hello everyone!' >"$file.tmp" &&
        cp -p -- "$file" "$file.old" &&
        mv -f -- "$file.tmp" "$file"
)
```

Note that if `$file` starts with `-` you will get errors from `xmlstarlet` and you cannot use `--` to separate it from true options. What we do here is to check whether the file name is absolute, and if not then we prepend `./`. You can omit the `cp` line if you do not need to save a copy of the original content.

Comment: `xmlstarlet` is great, with good [documentation](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php), but I find it hard to learn.

Comment: @reinierpost, there are a number of posts [here on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) and others [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) that show examples of its use. It is fiddly and the documentation isn't always as clear as it could be (I think it lacks real-world examples) but it can help particularly when you cannot guarantee the shape of the file structure

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a regex to parse HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

If you want to do it with `ed` the below will do it for the HTML tag you give it. But it might be better to use `sed`. This works because you can use any character with `s`, it doesn't have to be `s/old/new/` it can be `s|old|new|` or `s!old!new!`.

```
$ ed hello.html
28
,p
<title>Hello world!</title>
s|<title>.*</title>|<title>foo</title>|
,p
<title>foo</title>
```

> The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command. The / character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the regexp or replacement only if it is preceded by a \ character.

From https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html